# IIS Management Service IP and Port Bindings - How to Reset

Tags: windows, iis

In the process of configuring the IIS Management Service (to get the web deploy functionality working), I've somehow put it in a weird state where it thinks an IP address and port are already in use:

[image: error message]

I'm not sure what I did, in traditional fashion it's actually kind of complicated to get the web deploy stuff working and one of the steps in the un-install/re-install/repair loop did something.

I know the port and IP are not in use, verified through the outputs of `netstat`.  So I am thinking this info is being stored somewhere by IIS and then when you go to make to a config change, it looks there and sees a conflict and complains.

Does anyone know the location where these kinds of settings are stored?  Or how to reset them?  I checked applicationHost.config and they are not stored in there.

End of the day, I can bind the IIS Management Service to a different port but I'd like to keep it on the default if possible (no real reason, just for convenience).

Comment: I seems you define twice in IIS service the same IP:port pair in 2 listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting itself is stored in Windows registry,

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\IPAddress (REG_SZ)`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\Port (REG_DWORD)`

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/use-registry-keys
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/remote-administration-for-iis-manager#configure-wmsvc-settings

Comment: Many thanks Lex Li!  Just an additional note, after adjusting the values in the registry, one should check the Event Viewer to see if there are any errors, as I was still having some issues. 
 To complete the fix, using the IIS GUI, I performed the additional steps of: making a change the Web Management service bindings (I just selected another IP address, * would work too I think) then made one last final change where I set the IP and port to what I wanted.